# How do I get file metadata from URL

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

How do I get the data type from a file which is fetched from an URL string, e.g: 
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/MyApp.appspot.com/o/alertImgs%2Falert-1521356210850.jpg?alt=media&token=b6ad7e6e-1eb0-4e05-a11d-e59c8f1df365 (just an example)

When I fetch the URL with javascript from firebase firestore I need to know which data type have the file to put it on a video or image tag.

How can I acomplish this?

I'm working with ionic 3 and firebase.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse url and get last part of url as file name from which you can get extension of file and decide.

```js
function getFileNameFromUrl(url) {
  var el = document.createElement('a');
  el.href = url;
  return decodeURIComponent(el.pathname).split("/").pop();
}

console.log(getFileNameFromUrl("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/MyApp.appspot.com/o/alertImgs%2Falert-1521356210850.jpg?alt=media&token=b6ad7e6e-1eb0-4e05-a11d-e59c8f1df365"));
```

Comment: that's is how I'm already doing, but I want to assure because the file type in the URL could be wrong or even doesn't be indicated. :(

Comment: something like the getMetadata() of the firebase